# Upgrade to Grails 2.4: ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.4

I am trying to upgrade an application to Grails 2.4.5 from 2.3.11. I do not seem to be able to get this to work.
I use the Spring Security Core and Spring Security REST plugin. Trying to run the app, this exception is thrown indicating Spring Security Core as the source:

```
2015-04-29 16:20:24,497 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean
Message: org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean
[...]
|    212 | doCall                         in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure2
[...]
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean
```

Why doesn't it find the GenericFilterBean class? The Spring security plugin indicates that it is compatible with Grails 2.4.

The plugins are included in BuildConfig.groovy like this:

```
compile (":spring-security-rest:1.5.0.RC4")
compile (":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4")
```

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the reference documentation ? (Grails 2.4.x: upgrading from Grails 2.3)
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html

looks like a dependency error, please list out all the plugins being used in BuildConfig.groovy and the applicationContext.xml to have more clarity on the issue.